# How to make Git treat a directory like a different code base

Tags: git, github

I am using one of those static blog generators to publish my blog on Github pages, but I am having trouble organizing my Git repository.

I have two repositories on Github, one for source files of my blog and another one with final output of my blog. In my local copy, I have a file structure like this;

```
 / (main directory of source files)
    .git/
    output/
        .git
        ... other output files
    ... configuration and source files for static blog generator
```

I have made the outer Git directory ignore the output and made a new Git repository on output folder. However, it is not advised by the blog generator software to put any files in output directory and this makes me uncomfortable as I currently have `.git` folder there.

I was wondering if there was a clean solution to this problem. Something that would keep seperate history for output folder but doesn't put `.git` directory there should fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want to use is git submodules.

```
> git submodule add git@github.com:you/repo.git output
Cloning into 'output'...
```

See docs for more info http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Will this put the history of output folder inside `output/.git`? In that case, it won't solve my problem.

Comment: I'm unclear what the problem is with having the .git directory in /output? You need to track the changes in a separate repo, that's the only way to do it as far as I know.

Comment: Blog generation software might try to wipe output directory before processing source files. In that case, my .git folder might get deleted along with generated files.

Comment: try it? otherwise write a script to copy over the /output to another dir and submodule that!